# Changing output file name in Azure HDInsight

Tags: azure, file-format, azure-hdinsight

Using the [.NET SDK](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-submit-hadoop-jobs-programmatically/#mapreduce-sdk), I'm doing some log file parsing with Azure HDInsight. Seemingly simple things like changing the output file format from "part-xxxxx" to something related to the input file name seems to be quite complicated, and documentation is scant.

Based on what I've seen about [output file formats in Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileOutputFormat.html) in general, it looks like this isn't a setting I can change based on a template (which could then be fed in with HadoopJobConfiguration.AdditionalGenericArguments in the .NET SDK), but some actual Java code, which seems to suggest that the only way to get this done is to recode my solution as an actual Java class.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental Hadoop thing.

Hadoop jobs will always output files in part-nnnnn format, the only bit you can specify is the baseOutputDirectory path they will go in, so you could certainly use the directory to relate the output to the input.

The reason for this is that each reducer has to have its own output file.

If you're doing any further processing on the output in Hadoop, with Hive for example, then this shouldn't be too much of a hardship, since the InputFormats used will pick up all the part-nnnnn files for you.

That said, you could provide a subclass of the MultipleOutputFormat class to control the pattern of the filenames, but that will need to be in Java, since you can't write OutputFormats with the streaming API.

Another option might be to use the Azure Storage client to merge, and rename the output files once the